# Mouse.GetPostion(null) Equivalent in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mouse, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

What would be the equivalent for Mouse.GetPostion(null) which is in WPF.

I can get the position of pointer from the pointer event args. but how do i get the position without  any event. like "Mouse.GetPostion(null)" in WPF. where mouse is a static class. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `PointerPoint.Position` property - `PointerPoint` is a general input abstraction that also inludes touch and stylus input  so you have to get a focus on mouse input first - this can be done with a static

```
 PointerPoint PointerPoint.GetCurrentPoint(uint pointerId)
```

method where pointerId is a system generated number identifying the input device. I don't know if there is any other way but you can get the mouse PointerId through

```
PointerRoutedEventArgs.Pointer.PointerId
```

if you handle some mouse Pointer event like `PointerPressed` or `PointerReleased` first.